# Como fazer databind a uma texbox sem lhe atribuir um valor?

Tags: c#, textbox

Eu tenho uma textbox  txtEmail num método Display() onde eu lhe atribuo um email(atraves de uma query) para depois poder mostrar num perfil de um utilizador (tudo ok).

```
txtEmail.Text = item["email"].ToString();//devolve sapo.pt
```

Só que quando tento editar o valor através da query, se eu tentar editar escreve-me sempre o valor que ja tinha defenido anteriormente. alguma dica ?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Utilizadores SET NomePessoal=@NomePessoal, nifPessoal=@nifPessoal, contacto=@contacto, email=@email WHERE (idLogin = @idLogin)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text); // escrevo hotmail.com, mas fica na mesma com o valor sapo.pt
```

Eu faço o binding assim

```
//Seleção do perfil 
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                txtid.Text = item["idLogin"].ToString();
                txtNP.Text = item["NomePessoal"].ToString();
                txtUT.Text = item["Utilizador"].ToString();
                txtNif.Text = item["nifPessoal"].ToString();
                txtCon.Text = item["contacto"].ToString();
                txtTipo.Text = item["tipo"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else
```

Comment: Quando adiciona o parâmetro SQL o valor que é atribuído não é aquele que está na `TextBox`?

Comment: Supostamente sim , mas como eu acima lhe atribuo um valor a query faz update com o valor de cima e não o novo que eu escrevi, não sei porque

Comment: Se fizer `debug` que valor está no controlo `txtEmail`?

Comment: O valor é sapo.pt. Eu se retirar a atibuição à textbox acima o Updtade funciona , só que nao me faz display (mostra) o email anterior (fica vazia a textbox)

Comment: A `TextBox` está associada a algum `BindingSource`?

Comment: @JoãoMartins editei em cima , aquilo segue-se depois da query

Comment: @JoãoMartins alguma dica?

Comment: Ainda estou um bocado confuso sobre como o seu código está... principalmente a sequência do código. Não pode alterar a questão e colocar o código todo (se não for demais)?